# Why getting empty string after 'while' loop?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am creating a socket program using python. I have a function which receives 8 byte data from client each loop until it sends none. But after the loop the string prints empty. Here is my code,

```
def RequestHeader(conn):
    PACKET_SIZE = 8
    header = b''

    while True:
        data = conn.recv(PACKET_SIZE) # Receives 8 byte at a time.
        
        # If data is not empty, data is added to 'header'.
        if data:
            header += data 

        # if data is not sent (if it's b"") it will terminate the loop.
        else:
            break

    print(header.decode()) # Prints empty string, why?
```

Comment: Well, seems like data is empty the first time you run through the loop.

Comment: Did you try checking the value of `data` immediately after the `conn.recv` call?

Comment: Yes, I checked the value of data.. I was receiving bytes from client and it works all fine except the header is a empty string after it breaks loop also at 'else' body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local scope rule in python (from [Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names))

> If the definition occurs in a function block, the scope extends to any
> blocks contained within the defining one

The `header` variable should be the exact same value of the `header` at (after) `header += data`. Try printing header.

```
    if data:
        header += data
        print(header)
```

You should find that it is b'something'.

---

```
    print(header.decode()) # Prints empty string, why?
```

There are some cases it could print empty string:

- header is b''
- header is b'\r'

---

You could be wrong. The printed string is not empty. It could be any of the following:

- b' '
- b'\t'
- b'\n'

or these combined (also with \r).